# For each loop to display separate results

Tags: php, if-statement, foreach

I have a PHP code that takes an 'empfullname' from a drop down selection and displays a timecard based on the selection. However, I want to make it have the capability to allow a user to select 'All' and it just print all the employees available. I am thinking I have to do this with a foreach loop, but I can't seem to get it to work. Here is the if statement that I think I need.

```
if ($empfullname == 'All') {
  $query = "select * from ".$db_prefix."employees order by empfullname asc";
  $result = mysql_query($query);
  $tmp_empfullname = stripslashes("".$row['empfullname']."");
  foreach ($tmp_empfullname){
    print timecard_html($empfullname,$local_timestamp_in_week);
  } 
} else {
    print timecard_html($empfullname,$local_timestamp_in_week);
}
print '<script language="JavaScript" type=
       "text/javascript" src="../scripts/jquery.totals3.js"></script>';
print <<<End_Of_HTML

<table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="3" class="buttons">
    <tr><td><a href="timecardrpt.php"><img src=
           "../images/buttons/done_button.png" border="0" /></a></td></tr>
</table>
End_Of_HTML;

include '../footer.php';
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a huge mess and it's clear you aren't thinking through the logic or structure very well and you haven't looked at many examples of PHP MySQL functions. There are TONS of examples and tutorials you should be looking at. Regarding foreach, you need to understand [how foreach works](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php). Specifically, the syntax is `foreach ($myArray as $value)` and not just `foreach ($myArray)`. There's a lot of other stuff as well.

1. You don't run any query in your "else" block.
2. You don't fetch rows from the result.
3. You use the deprecated and insecure mysql function instead of [mysqli](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).
4. You are inconsistent in your variable names (you have `$tmp_empfullname` in your foreach but `$empfullname` in the statement block.
5. Strictly speaking, you don't need a foreach loop as a while works fine. You could use a foreach, but meh.

This should fix it:

```
//Do your mysqli connection here. it's different from the mysql connection.

if ($empfullname == 'All') {
    $query = "select * from ".$db_prefix."employees order by empfullname asc";
} else {
    $query = //put a SQL query here
}

if ($result = mysqli->query($query)){
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){ //you could also do foreach ($result as $row)
        print timecard_html(stripslashes($row['$empfullname']), $local_timestamp_in_week);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your solution did not work. It did not display any results for either selection then.

Comment: You should verify that you're executing the MySQLI connection properly. You should probably post more of your code in the question because there's a dozen things that could be going wrong in your code.

Answer (score 0):

The poblem is that you are calling this $row without ever declaring it in a foreach so you should make the code after `$result = mysql_query($query);` look like:

```
foreach ($result as $row) {
    $tmp_empfullname = stripslashes("".$row['empfullname']."");
}
```

Once that is done you should just need to do what Aleatoric to get each name that is in the `$tmp_empfullname` variable.